# WCF Service Library template not available on Visual Studio 2013 express?

Tags: wcf, templates, visual-studio-2013

I really want to develop using the WCF Service Library template, but I am concluding that it is not available on the express version.  Can anyone confirm?  I've tried the installVStemplates, and re- installing the software.  No luck it seems.  Am hoping I might be wrong somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WCF Service Library is, in essence, a class library (DLL) that contains the service contract and its implementation (or just the implementation if the contract is in a separate project).

While the WCF Service Library template is a convenient way to create a WCF Service library, the only things it adds are the `IService1.cs/vb` interface, `Service1.cs/vb` implementation, some boiler plate code, and references to `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.ServiceModel`.

If you don't have the template, you can do the following:

1. Create a new Class Library in the language of your choice.
2. Rename `Class1.cs` to your service name.
3. Add an interface for the service contract.
4. Add a reference to `System.ServiceModel` and `System.Runtime.Serialization` (the latter if you'll be using DataContracts).

I haven't used the express editions since 2010, and I don't remember if you can create class libraries with Visual Web Developer Express, so you might need to use Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

It's a little extra work without the template (about 5 minutes or less), but you can still do it.

Comment: Many thanks sir!  I am doing a face palm - of course, all I needed to do was add the correct references to the class library (System.ServiceModel and System.Runtime.Serialization mainly) and the hundreds of errors I'd gotten - because the [Datacontract] and other WCF attributes weren't recognized - went away.