# Questions on WCF regarding Class lirbary and also reg. DataContract

Tags: wcf

URL: http://wcftutorial.net/Introduction-to-WCF.aspx

**Question 1:**

Above tutorial mentions a Tip:-

a. Define the service in Class library and refer the class library in Host project. Don’t use service class in host project.

b. Always create the service with Interface->Implementation format, mention the contract in Interface.

c. Define the service in Class library and refer the class library in Host project. Don’t use service class in host project.

Question: Does the good practice suggest to create another class library rather then the existing IService1.cs and Service1.svc? Can anyone here give me an example of what author is trying to say in the above points?

**Question 2:**
When I create a new WCF application it has got IService1.cs and Service1.svc. All the implementation I have coded under Service1.svc.cs

Under the IService1.cs there is Service and Operation Contract, data contract (What is purpose of data contract here? can I delete it off?).

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer of Question 1

Yes you need to create a separate class library for your service and a separate host project.See the following

[image]

You need to create something like this. Add Reference of AngService in AngServiceHost Application.

AngServiceHost Application is WCF Application. Delete the Service1.cs and IService1.cs

Add following lines in Service1.svc in AngServiceHost

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="AngService.ILogin" %>
```

> Answer of Question 2

Whatever you have coded in .svc.cs file should go in the service class library, not in the host application.

Understand that the .svc file is used for hosting. You can reference the source of the service in this .svc file. In my example the dll of AngService (the class library) is added in AngServiceHost(the host application). This dll contains the actual code. You need to do something similar to this.

Comment: Then finally you deploy the AngServiceHost to IIS. Right?

Comment: Yes. You have to deploy AngServiceHost to IIS. Edit the webconfig of AngServiceHost according to your requirement.

Comment: Can you share some code that shows how you use the other class library inside the AngServiceHost application project please. Also can you share any changes that need to be done to web.config

Comment: You just need to build the Service Class Library. Right click on AngServiceHost and select `Reference`. Modify the .svc class same as I gave you in answer. Run it. Host it on IIS. Then make client application, it can be a website or a Windows Forms application or a console application. Right click and select `Add Service Reference`. Pass the URL of your service.

Comment: OK. So for the WCF application host project, in the Service1.svc, we only need to write <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="AngService.ILogin" %> and nothing else like c# code. is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. No c# code is required in host application.

Comment: If no code is written in host application, then how will the host application understand which method of the service library to invoke when some client application is consuming this host application?

Comment: Your host gives reference of `AngService.ILogin` Interfece. This interface is the `Service Contract`. All the methods in this interface having `[OperationContract]` attribute can be invoked.

Comment: OK, so as per your implementation strategy, you are invoking the WCF service library methods from the host application. Is that right? Is this the WCF Host application or the consumer. I am confused. I want to host the WCF in IIS. I think your answer is with respect to self hosting WCF

Comment: You have 3 Applications. AngService, is the service class library having Interface and the implementation of interface.
Second, you have AngServiceHost which has the .svc file.
Third, You have a Consumer Application from where you call the methods to consume the service.

Comment: No. I deleted the file. It was of no use in my case.

Comment: Can you provide me a example case in which we would need to write code/keep that cs file

Comment: Can you tell me if you add the service library to the host project via right click host project -> 'add reference' or via 'right click host project ->add service reference'?

Comment: Right Click host project `Add Reference`

Comment: OK I have added the reference, then modified the svc in editor and added <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MYservicelibrary.IService1" %> or do I need to add a '.CS' at end of the line?

Comment: No you don't need to add .cs at end. Also See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service) link. It explains what I did.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to suggest you reading the basics of WCF in a book "Learning WCF" from Michele Leroux Bustamante, if you have an option to get it - the tutorial you are linking to was too chaotic by my opinion (I was reading it some time ago too)

**Question 1**: The thing is, that you should define 2 projects - 1 will contain host of the service and second will contain definition/implementation of that service. See picture below: [image: Svc]

In ServiceHost, I ussualy have only main entry point, which launches the host. In ServiceLibrary (you can choose whatever name suits you) I have the service interface and implementation. Also, please notice that in ServiceHost, I have referenced ServiceLibrary.

**Question2**: Simply said: DataContracts are used when you are working with your custom objects over WCF. Lets say you want to get information about "Person" from you service. You can either define for example 3 OperationContracs - first would return name (string), second one age of that person (int) and third one telephone number (int).
 But this is not the way you should proceed - you should return Person object from service (in your case, you have "CompositeType"). For that, you need to mark the class with `[DataContract]` attribute and all the information you want to exchange with `[DataMember]` attribute.

Of course you dont need to have the definition of "CompositeType" in IService - you can create new class in your project, name it "CompositeType" and mark it as `[DataContract]`.

Is it more clear?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in easy language. Can you tell me the visual studio template you used to create both the above projects please.

Comment: For ServiceHost, you can simply use "Console Application" template. For ServiceLibrary, I used "Class Library" template.

Comment: Don't you choose a WCF template (example: WCF service library, or WCF application template?)? I need to deploy the solution eventually to IIS. So it works like a webservice.

Comment: Well, you can choose WCF service library as well if you want, but regarding to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976452/wcf-service-library-template-not-available-on-visual-studio-2013-express   It only adds IService.cs, Service.cs classes and automaticaly provides you with ServiceModel and Serialization reference - you can do all of it by yourself in like 1 minute, if you choose simple "Class library". So its up to you :)

Comment: What about the other project. Isnt that template compulsorily need to be WCF service application type?

Comment: You can check what does the template contains here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb552362(v=vs.110).aspx  . Again, WCF service application template containts same thing as library, but it also contains class for hosting (not good idea for bigger projects I believe). The service Im working on in my job has been developed using standard Console Application (host), Class Library (service implementation) and WinForms (client application) and its working.

Comment: Question 1: Ok so you are not deploying the service to IIS? Right? You are deploying it as dll and consuming via a console application?... Question 2: You said that the best practice is to move all my code (definition and implementation) into a serviceproject (which can be either service library or class library project). Then, add dll of this project to another project called host (which can be either class library or wcf host application). Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am self hosting the service using ConsoleApplication. But using different configuration, I can switch it to IIS (although I havent tried). Yes, your service definition should be in a separate project and you should include reference to it in host (right click Reference>Add Reference>Solution (if you have both library and host in same solution) and choose the projct with service library.

Comment: After I add the service library as reference in the host project, what C# code do I need to write inside the HOST project so that the host application should understand which method of the service library to invoke when some client application is consuming this host application?

Comment: Well the methods will be known to client by adding "Service reference" in client. But for configuring the host, you can check for example this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784084/WCF-Self-Hosting-in-a-Console-Application-Simplifi   it shows what to define in host. Just remember, that most of the definitions in host could be defined in App.Config (Web.Config) as well.

Comment: THe post is about self hosting WCF. Means, there is service library with all implementation. Also, there is console app which hosts the above service library and calls various methods... I am trying to create a WCF that will be deployed to IIS. Still do you advice me to use the service library project and host project?. Then, host the host project in IIS? So that my consumers will call the Host project to invoke methods of the service lirbary? Is that right?

Comment: If you really want to start with IIS, you can use this tutorial instead: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service . I was just linking some "hosting" basics in previous one. IIS is a littble bit different of course.

Comment: But do you still advice the same project structure (ie: service lirbary, then use dll of this in a host project. Then host the host project in IIS?)? OR do you think it is enough in my case that I only create the WCF service application (which has got all code and implementation, etc), then publish this  to IIS and allow my client applciations to consume it?

Comment: I would suggest considering separating the service contract (definition) from the service library (implementation). I typically structure my WCF solutions into the following four parts: Service Contract, Service Library, Service Host, Client.

Comment: Yes, I would advise you to stick to the best practice and divide host from service implementation. That is the way people are doing it.   EDIT: Or as Derek W says, separate it even more.

Comment: Here are a couple of articles on best practices for assembly separation for WCF: [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273127%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [CodeMag Article](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101)